# Azure DevOps: Data Factory Pipeline: A managed private endpoint to the data source already exist

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, azure-data-factory, azure-rm-template

I'm facing a problem while deploying an ADF project in the stating env using my CI/CD pipeline.

I'm using Azure DevOps.
I'm using a release pipeline, triggered when a new build is available (each validated PR on the main branch triggers a new build).
Pipeline has one stages : staging.
I am using a managed private endpoint connecting an ADLS account. This was causing me some problems.

I am getting following error while doing deployment to staging env,

```
InvalidResourceRequest: Invalid resource request. Resource type: 
'ManagedPrivateEndpoint', Resource name: 'XXX-YYY' 
'Error: A managed private endpoint to the data source already exist.'
```

I know that managed endpoint is already exist but cant we overwrite or skip it while doing the deployment to staging env.

Answer (score 1):

Going through the best practices [CI CD ADF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery#best-practices-for-cicd)

> If a private endpoint already exists in a factory and you try to deploy an ARM template that contains a private endpoint with the same name but with modified properties, the deployment will fail.